# Excel VBA Case not recognizing value of cell

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Im trying to use VBA to hide/show a group of rows on a separate sheet within the same workbook named `Invoice`

To do this, on the `InputForm` sheet, there is a cell (`N14`) which uses `=ISBLANK(D53)` to check if `D53` contains anything and obviously returns `TRUE/FALSE`

From this im trying to run an If Statement in VBA to hide/show rows based on whether the cell `N14` contains `TRUE/FALSE`

The code i've tried works ok if i manually type TRUE/FALSE but not if it is automatically entered by the formula.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False) = "N14" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case "TRUE": Sheets("Invoice").Rows("57:123").Hidden = True:
    Case "FALSE": Sheets("Invoice").Rows("57:123").Hidden = False:
End Select
End If
End Sub
```

The format of Cell N14 is "Text"

Comment: try to remove quotes: `Case True:` instead `Case "TRUE":`

Comment: or simply use `Sheets("Invoice").Rows("57:123").Hidden = Target.Value` instead `Select Case` statement

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @simoco, quotes are removed but the same problem. Works ok if entered manually but not when the formula does it

Comment: btw, `Worksheet_Change` doesn't fires when _result_ of your _formula_ changes. It fires only if you change _value_ of cell itself. Look into `Worksheet_Calculate` event with single line of code:  `Sheets("Invoice").Rows("57:123").Hidden = Range("N14").Value`

Comment: Thanks again @simoco

`Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Sheets("Invoice").Rows("57:123").Hidden = Range("N" & 14).Value = 1

    End Sub`

This works but it gives a Out of stack space (Error 28)

Comment: why do you use `= 1` in the end? And also try to add `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the beggining of `Worksheet_Calculate` event and `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the very end

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Still

`Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Sheets("Invoice").Rows("57:123").Hidden = Range("N14").Value

End Sub`

Give same Error 28

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Invoice").Rows("57:123").Hidden = Range("N14").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub`

Seems to be working!

Thanks for all your help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, `Worksheet_Change` doesn't fires when *result* of your *formula* changes. It fires only if you change *value* of cell itself. You should look into `Worksheet_Calculate` event instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Invoice").Rows("57:123").Hidden = Range("N14").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```